# how to add header to spark RDD in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to add header to spark RDD in Scala and I have tried union,

```
headerrdd.union(temRet).coalesce(1, false).saveAsTextFile(retPath)
```

but sometimes the header comes at the end of the file . what should I do ? I want the header at the begin of the file.

Comment: What version of spark are you using? In newer versions (2.0.0+) you can use dataframes which can automatically add a header for you.

Comment: spark 2.2  , thank you , i'll  try

Comment: i have tried ,temRet.coalesce(1).write.option("header", true)  cannot saveAsTextFile

Comment: why don't you create a dataframe from the existing rdd with header and save the output with head in text format?

Comment: meahwhile you can use coalesce two times as `headerrdd.union(temRet.coalesce(1, false)).coalesce(1, false).saveAsTextFile(retPath)`.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan  I have tried as you say , use coalesce two times , but it can't work, sometimes the header comes at the end of the file. And i have to process the dataframe before i save it as a text file, and ,how to save a dataframe as a textfile with header?

Comment: best is to convert the rdd to dataframe and save it as text file then